# Stretch SVG inline tag as when embedded with img tag

Tags: html, css, svg

In a page I have a svg image embedded directly in the html and I would like that this svg stay always 100% width in a responsive design and maintaining the original proportions.

I tried playing with **preserveAspectRatio** but I'm not able to stretch the width image preserving the proportions in the exactly same way that I'm able to do when embedding the image with an img tag and an external svg file.

[See the example on jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/manzapanza/s3Vq2/embedded/result/)

```
    <h2>A) Svg embedding an svg element directly in the HTML:</h2>
    <svg
        version="1.1"
        xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
        xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink"
        x="0px"
        y="0px"
        width="200px"
        height="300px"
        viewBox="0 0 200 300"
        preserveAspectRatio="xMinYMin"
        xml:space="preserve" style="background-color:#000; width: 100%;">

        <line fill="none" stroke="#E32A2D" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="16.3" y1="247.1" x2="39" y2="258.7"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#E32A2D" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="39" y1="258.8" x2="61.8" y2="270.2"/>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#E32A2D" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M61.9,270.3c7.6,3.8,15.2,7.6,22.8,11.3"/>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#E32A2D" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M84.8,281.6c3.8,1.8,7.7,3.7,11.5,5.5c1,0.5,1.9,0.8,3,1.2c0.5,0.2,1,0.5,1.6,0.3c0.6-0.1,1-0.2,1.6-0.3c2.1-0.4,4.2-0.9,6.2-1.4"/>
        <path fill="none" stroke="#E32A2D" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" d="M108.6,287c8.3-1.8,16.5-3.9,24.8-5.9"/>
        <line fill="none" stroke="#E32A2D" stroke-width="6" stroke-miterlimit="10" x1="133.5" y1="281.1" x2="158.2" y2="275"/>
    </svg>

    <h2>B) Svg using img element:</h2>
    <img src="image.svg" width="100%">
```

I would like that the example A had the same behavior of the example B, but how?

Should be visible at least on Chrome and Safari

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your ViewBox element you're going to have to play with the numbers to fit it.

The viewbox attribute has the following attributes:

```
min-x min-y width height
```

But that's within the scope of it's own grid system *within* the svg.

This article should help.

[Madness with SVG viewbox](http://www.justinmccandless.com/blog/Making+Sense+of+SVG+viewBox%27s+Madness)

Comment: Works fine for me in chrome.

Comment: Look it in a wide window. This is the jsfiddle embedded view of your code version: http://jsfiddle.net/manzapanza/w2rJA/1/embedded/result/ I tested it on: Firefox Mac/Win and work correctly, but.. on Chrome Mac/Win/Android, Safari Mac/iOS unfortunately don't work

Comment: Your image is not displaying, what's the desired outcome? A really tall image that spans 100%?

Comment: The image should stretch to 100% of width available and "automatically" to have an height calculated proportionally.. as happens when is embedded the svg with the img tag and width="100%"

Comment: Re-did answer to help. Not the exact solution, but it'll get you on the right track for a solution.